# Distance of rainbow from observer

Tags: optics, atmospheric-science

I have been reading about rainbows and I know that there is a different rainbow for each observer. Also the rainbow is centred on a **line** joining the head of a person to his shadow. What does it mean? I suppose that this means that a rainbow has some "thickness"(am I right?). So my question is that although a rainbow cannot be given a distance from a given observer( as it is visible to a given person over a range of distances), what are the factors which determine that range over which a rainbow is most prominent from point of view of given observer.

Thanks

Comment: this is like asking "how far away is the mirror", well, how far away is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How deep is a rainbow?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187591/how-deep-is-a-rainbow) (just a little more trigonometry should do the trick)

Comment: @JEB, Yeah, but a mirror is a _flat_ thing, and even if it's so clean and so perfect that you can't see the mirror itself, you still can use trigonometry to calculate the apparent distance to your own reflection, divide by two, and learn precisely where the mirror _must_ be.  The rainbow is different because the water drops do not all lie in a plane, and they do not obey the same [law of reflection](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/refln/Lesson-1/The-Law-of-Reflection).